# Animal Companion advancement option?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions, optional-rules

I rolled a Cavalier as a random class in a Skulls and Shackles game for a little extra excitement. Being a masochist I decided to roll with it, but took more than a couple optional rules/variants in order to make a class that's supposed to be about teamwork and horses work in a setting that's about pillaging and ships.

At the end of the day I ended up with a Human Cavalier using the Huntmaster  Archetype, with an Osprey Animal Companion.

While looking through some min-max threads, I stumbled upon this one, which mentions an advancement variant whereby I could give my AC +2 DEX at level 4 instead of +2 STR:

[How to create a useful bird companion?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40736/how-to-create-a-useful-bird-companion)

While this option seems fantastic, I can't seem to find mention of it anywhere. Has anyone seen this option in the wild, and if so can you provide me a source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is listed in the [Animal Companions Description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Animal-Companion-Descriptions) header:

> As you gain levels, your animal companion improves as well, usually at
>   4th or 7th level, in addition to the standard bonuses noted on Table:
>   Animal Companion Base Statistics. **Instead of taking the listed
>   benefit at 4th or 7th level, you can instead choose to increase the
>   companion's Dexterity and Constitution by 2.**